# “Connect: Network is unreachable” when pinging 8.8.8.8

Tags: networking, lubuntu, resolv.conf

I installed lubuntu 18.04 onto my Windows 10 laptop, but I am unable to ping 8.8.8.8.

Here are my specs for my computer:

- Architecture: i686
- CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit
- Byte Order: Little Endian
- CPU(s): 2
- On-line CPU(s) list: 0,1
- Vendor ID: GenuineIntel
- CPU family: 6
- Model: 76
- Model Name: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N3060 @ 1.60GHz

I added “nameserver 8.8.8.8” to /etc/resolv.conf but when I tried to ping 8.8.8.8, it says connect: Network is unreachable. I am able to ping local host though.

```
 ip a
 
 
 1: lo :<LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000 link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever inet6 :: 1/128 scope host valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
 2: enp3s0: <NO CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_code1 state DOWN group default qlen 1000 link/ether c8:5b:76:7a:8b:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
 3: wlp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000 link/ether c8:3d:d4:3a:88:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Can you post output of "ip a".

Comment: @ThomasAichinger

1: lo :<LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
     link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
     inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
     inet6 :: 1/128 scope host
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_code1 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
     link/ether c8:5b:76:7a:8b:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: @ThomasAichinger

3: wlp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000

link/ether c8:3d:d4:3a:88:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: Hi Holly - both of your network cards report that they are not connected to networks.  localhost (127.0.0.1) is your computer.

Comment: Just so you know, Lubuntu's support for 18.04 ends in a month. Putting any effort into it is not advised as there is no supported upgrade path to the newer versions of Lubuntu as they're a major shift to LXQt. You might just as well install 20.04 (overwriting 18.04) to see if the problem still exists.

Comment: @KGIII Will Lubuntu 20.04 work well on a Windows 2017 laptop or should I use ubuntu instead? I read somewhere I need to use Lubuntu if I am using an old laptop. Unfortunately, I didn't do a dual boot on the old laptop.

Comment: It's lighter than Ubuntu, so yes. Yes, it'll run. It should run just fine on your laptop. I don't know how much RAM you have, but lots of people are using Lubuntu on computers that aren't that powerful.

Comment: @KGIII Thanks for the clarification. I'll try installing the new version of Lubuntu on my USB and see if it will work.

Comment: @KGIII I was able to install the new version of Lubuntu (20.10) and add 8.8.8.8 as a name server for /etc/resolv.conf. Unfortunately when I try pinging it again, it says the following:
`ping: connect: Network is unreachable`

Comment: Undo that change you made and then do it with the GUI - right click on the network icon in the system tray, edit connections, edit the connection specifically, and add it as DNS. It's likely in the Lubuntu online manual, but you should be able to find it on your own.

Comment: It seems that you have not configured your network. What type you want to use cable or wifi? Post your /etc/netplan/*,yaml file to see what you have configured,

Comment: @KGIII Thank you! After I asked my question, I figured out where to find the network icon and all that jazz. It now works :)

Comment: @ThomasAichinger Thank you for your response. After installing the newest version of Lubuntu onto my USB drive, it was able to work. :)

Comment: Glad it's sorted. It's much easier to just do it with the GUI (and all that jazz). I think you're supposed to add both 8.8.8.8 and the other one. I want to say it's 8.8.4.4 but you should verify it. You're trying to use Google's DNS servers, correct? If so, there are two of 'em to add and I'm pretty sure the 2nd one is 8.8.4.4 for completeness.